# Rails Form select : preselect one choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this rails code :

```
 <% status_a = [ ["DRAFT", "DRAFT"], ["OPEN", "OPEN"], ["CLOSE", "CLOSE"] ] %>
 <%= form_for(:dash_action, url: brokers_dashboard_path ) do |f| %>
      <%= f.select(:select_status, options_for_select(status_a), {}, selected:'OPEN' %>
 <% end %>
```

When it runs, it generates this HTML code :

```
<select selected="selected" name="dash_action[select_status]" id="dash_action_select_status">
<option value="DRAFT">DRAFT</option>
<option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
<option value="CLOSE">CLOSE</option>
...
```

But what I expect is : 
**selected="OPEN" and not "selected"**

Why the select method is not doing what I want ?

Comment: `<%= f.select(:select_status, options_for_select(status_a), selected:'OPEN' %>`

Comment: no, that does not help. I got this :
`<select name="dash_action[select_status]" id="dash_action_select_status">
<option value="DRAFT">DRAFT</option>
<option value="OPEN">OPEN</option>
<option value="CLOSE">CLOSE</option>
...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code snippet, default value should be the parameter of `options_for_select`

```
f.select :select_status, options_for_select(status_a, 'OPEN')
```